# Nginx Rule - if not in directory

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I use this code for add expires to static files:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
expires 30d;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control “public”;
log_not_found off;
}
```

I have some random images in the virutual directory /image/. When the code above is in Nginx, the random images get a 404.

I dont need expires for the directory /image/. For this directory the code should not run. How is it possible to write something like this in Nginx language:

```
If not /image/
 {

  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ 
  {
  expires 30d;
  add_header Pragma public;
  add_header Cache-Control “public”;
  log_not_found off;
  }

 }
```

Comment: The images should still be served from this directory?

Comment: No, its not necessary that nginx serve the image from there. Best would be, when the expire code runs only, when its not the /image/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$
{
   if ($request_uri !~ ^/image/.*) {
        expires 30d;
    }
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    log_not_found off;
}
```

Comment: thank you for getting into. There comes an error: Error nginx-Konfiguration: nginx: [emerg] location "/image/" is outside